# 400 bad request error in jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to send a AJAX post request using jquery  and get that 
data in Flask. I am retrieving the data and storing that in values

```
//capturing values which are entered

var values = $("input[id='task']")
            .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
alert(values);
postData(values);
break;

//js code

function postData(input) {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
      data: JSON.stringify({ "text" : input } ),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert("successful");
      },
      error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
          }
       });
    }

//Flask code
def login():
print("here")
datafromjs = request.get_json()
print(datafromjs)
return jsonify(datafromjs)
return render_template('index.html');
```

what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If that's the full Flask code, you'll need to add `@app.route('/login')` above your `login` function.